# How to get Object of Current activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, task

I want to get `Bitmap` object of current window in my app. But my application running in background.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) BackGroundAppScreenActivity.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> infoList = manager.getRunningTasks(100);

RunningTaskInfo m = infoList.get(0);

String activityName = m.topActivity.getClassName();
```

By this code I got name of current foreground activity.. But I am unable to get Bitmap of screen..